# how do I query SQLite database with two conditions?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table about employee with 3 columns like following code:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DEPT
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + CITY + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

now I just want to show employees in the same both DEPT and CITY(e.i both employees in HCM City and Sales department). How can I query to get it?

Answer (score 11):

@DienTrinh, you had it right, note the spaces around `AND`. That should work for you.

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, 
                          new String [] {_ID, NAME, DEPT, CITY }, 
                          DEPT +"=?" +" AND " + CITY +"=?", 
                          new String[] {"Sales", "HCM" }, 
                          null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM Employess 
WHERE DEPT='Sales' COLLATE NOCASE AND City='HCM' COLLATE NOCASE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE DEPT='Sales' AND City='HCM'
```

Comment: it works in SQL but it doesn't work in SQLite. How can I use that command in SQLite with syntax: db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy).

Comment: I tried to use  Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String [] {_ID, NAME, DEPT, CITY } , DEPT +"=?" +"AND" +CITY +"=?" , new String[] {"Sales", "HCM" }, null, null, null);. But the emulator show an error

Comment: Shouldn't this type of query be ran with the db.rawQuery method rather than db.query? I think that was the problem.