# What exactly is where?whereval in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

There are two pieces of code,which i thought were similar ,but one gives me an error and one doesn't,so I have a few questions to ask

What exactly is "where","whereval"?
The below code gives me an error

```
 String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
                  + "="+img.get(position).Album;//here is the difference 
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                  where, null , orderBy);//whereval is null here
```

The below code doesn't give me any error

```
String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
                  + "=?";here is the difference 
 String whereVal[] =  {img.get(position).Album};here is the difference 

 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                  where, whereVal , orderBy);//i have included whereVal
```

Please explain me the difference between the two pieces of code ??

Also how can i use two conditions in sqlite ??

Comment: just a comment `managedQuery` is deprecated since API 11. Now you should you use `CursorLoader`

Comment: @Budius thanx for that i realized that a bit late...but did you understand my question ?

Comment: it gives you a column not found error because the ? syntax escapes the parameters, while using direct string concatenation results in a query that matches 2 columns, one of which is the value of Album, which is not a column.

Comment: one will result in Album = Some Album, while the other results in Album = 'Some Album'.

Comment: @njzk2 ok thank you...so "?" is for the value while direct "=" is for column ..is that what you are saying ?Also how can i use two conditions ??

Comment: two conditions you use just like in any sql query, with or or and, depending on your needs

Comment: @njzk2 suppose i have to use the code1 to achieve the result that i am getting from code 2..what should be the syntax ??

Comment: you'd have to escape by hand, but you don't want to do that, as you'd have to sanitize your inputs as well, which is totally boring.

Comment: @njzk2 please check the below answer and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, string literals are quoted `'like this'`. If you insert a string literal in SQL without the quotes, you'll likely get an SQL syntax error. It's the same as in Java where `"any string"` without the quotes is unlikely to be valid Java code but it's valid as a string literal.

`?` is a placeholder for a literal. The SQL is compiled with the placeholder in place and the literal value is bound to the compiled statement. Think of it as a variable in programming languages. The value for the variable comes from the bind arguments. In Android Java sqlite wrapper, the bind args are supplied in the string array.

Further reading: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam - though the Android wrapper code adds some leaky abstractions on top of sqlite C API.

> suppose i have to use the code1 to achieve the result that i am getting from code 2..what should be the syntax ??

Quote the string literal with `'...'`:

```
String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
              + "='"+img.get(position).Album+"'";
```

Based on the comments you want a conjuction expression. Just add an `AND` between subexpressions, like

```
String where = "foo='bar' AND baz='xyzzy'";
```

Comment: suppose i have to use the code1 to achieve the result that i am getting from code 2..what should be the syntax ??

Comment: String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
            + "='"+img.get(position).Album+"'";// AND "+android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST+"="+cursor2.getString(0);

Comment: the answer given here should answer the question you asked in comment

Comment: @njzk2 yes well it has been edited now...so it does answer it ...but i was getting confused with these single and double quotes so i checked this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347572/how-do-i-query-sqlite-database-with-two-conditions which was helpful

Comment: you could also consider reading the documentation regarding the quotes on sqlite : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html